# How to add horizontal whitespace in my text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation

I have the following problem:

[image]

Is there an easy and quick way to change the upper part to the lower? I tried using `\hspace`, but it had no effect. I'm new to TeX so bear with me ;D

Comment: You might look into the [hanging](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hanging) package.

Comment: I thin you need a `\begin{description}` environment. BTW `\hspace` won't work at the beginning of the line. Use `\hspace*{...}` instead.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help! `\hspace*{...}` did the job!, I will try the `\begin{description}` also. Thank you again! Much appreciated =)

Comment: What about `\hangindent` and `\hangafter`?

Comment: +1 I tried the `\hangindent`. It worked too =) Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a simple `list`-type environment, such as `itemize`

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[Lorem ipsum] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
     text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    \item[Lorem ipsum] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
     text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

If you want to customize it a little, then the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) can help- for example

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[font=\bf]
    \item[Lorem ipsum] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
     text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    \item[Lorem ipsum] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
     text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

A lot is possible here- you are only limited by imagination!

Comment: It seems preferable in terms of layout as well as semantic markup to use a `description` list, as Harish suggested (even though this slightly from the requested layout).